# How do I connect my local site to an empty GitHub repository with the windows GUI?

Tags: git, github, repository

I am having the hardest time finding an answer to what seems like a very simple github related question.

I have a site built out locally.  Lets say its located `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySite`.  There is an empty GitHub repository set up on GitHub: MyGitHub/ProjectOne.

I have the GitHub windows gui up and running and can see the github repository but I can't figure out how to create a local repository where my existing local site is located.  When I try to do use the 'clone to' command it creates a github folder within the MySite directory like this: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySite\ProjectOne.  But I want the MySite directory to be the repository, not a folder within.

How do I make my repository be the actual MySite directory?  I need to commit the whole MySite directory to the empty github repository but I don't want to have to copy the files to a different folder.

Any tips?  I feel like there is something I'm not understanding.

Comment: No - but I've never used it before (or Git, obviously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did try downloading the GitHub windows gui, but found it confusing.  I did not let me choose where to create an empty repository, or let me choose which already existing github repository to push to.  It wanted to create a new one.  Maybe that is the answer, delete the empty one on github and let the windows client do the work.  I do not have faith in this however.

You should have the git commands locally and something like this should work.  You should see something like this mentioned on github.

```
cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySite
git remote add origin git@github.com:MyGitHub/ProjectOne.git
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: This basically worked with a few tweaks. I had to set an upstream origin master and do a git pull. But everything is working now.  Thanks for the help.  The command line actually seems easier than the windows GUI so I think I'll just use that from now on

Answer (score 0):

If you want `MySite` to be the repo, you can create it from the command line

```
cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySite
git init
git add 
git commit
```